# Xdebug via SSH in PhpStorm - doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I have project via SSH in PhpStorm.

I'm trying run PHPUnit script with debugger and I see this message:

> Connection with 'Xdebug 2.6.0' was not established

In xdebug.log I see:

```
Log opened at 2018-07-11 08:52:42
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 46.170.254.34:9001.
W: Creating socket for '46.170.254.34:9001', poll success, but error:  Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-07-11 08:52:42
```

In console I see:

> ssh://xxxx@xxxx.pl:22/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9001 -dxdebug.remote_host=11.11.11.11 /home/path/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /home/path/vendor/autoload.php --configuration /home/path/phpunit.xml --filter "/(::testGettingMe)( .*)?$/" App\Tests\Functional\Context\Api\MeControllerTest /home/path/tests/Functional/Context/Api/MeControllerTest.php --teamcity

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does not stop? Well .. it does not even manage to connect to IDE... Is IP address correct one? Just in case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne 
I created simple php file on my remote server. I set one breakpoint. I created new debug cenfiguration for this script in PhpStorm. I click debug and PhpStorm send commend to serwer: `ssh://user@server.pl:22/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9001 -dxdebug.remote_host=11.11.11.11 /home/path/public/tt.php`, where 11.11.11.11 is my local computer ip and this ip is correct. In php.ini on server i have: 
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_timeout=200

Comment: I'm confused with IPs. I could be wrong here ... but AFAIK it should not use your local PC IP when doing it over SSH. Right now it might be trying to connect to your PC via internet .. and your firewall/router may be blocking it. I would suggest using SSH tunnel (the link with all details can be found in that link I gave you) so Xdebug connect to 127.0.0.1 and SSH forwards it to your local PC. Other than that your Xdebug config part seem to be OK. Sorry, but I have not done debugging PHPUnit over SSH myself; only ordinary scripts/web pages where SSH Tunnel works fine for me.